# A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource

Tags: xml, asp.net

Here is the exact error I'm getting when I try to launch my default.aspx file from the published folder. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

```
The XML page cannot be displayed 
Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet. Please correct the error and then click the Refresh button, or try again later. 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

A name was started with an invalid character. Error processing resource 'file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MHNProServices/Default....

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ProServices.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"...
```

Here are the contents of default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/ProServices.Master" AutoEventWireup="False" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MHNProServices.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link type="text/css" href="css/Default.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div id="contentHead">
           <img src="css/img/heading_landing.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div id="contentTop"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="contentLeft">
            <asp:Image ID="displayPicture" runat="server" />
            <img id="displayOverlay"src="css/img/profilepicture_overlay.gif" />

            <a id="contentButton_makeAppointment" href="Appointments.aspx?step=start"></a>
            <a id="contentButton_cancelAppointment" href="Appointments.aspx?step=cancel"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="contentRight">
                <h3><asp:Label ID="lbl_homepageHeader" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h3>
                <hr />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_homepageContent" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contentBottom"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

This was because I was launching the .aspx file directly from the folder I published it to - I needed to have it up on an IIS server. D'OH!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the contents of the file (C:/inetpub/wwwroot/MHNProServices/Default....) or the code that references this is necessarily just a guess.

Either there is an invalid character in the file, or the `'` at the beginning of the file name means the reference to the file is incorrect.

Comment: I updated my post with the contents. The website works fine when it is run from visual studio 2008.